# Time series- Not periodic, despite having included frequency

Tags: time-series, rstudio

This is actually part of my thesis research, where I have to run a time series analysis on pollution and economic growth of a single country.

I have data of over 144 years of the two variables with each value representing a single year. I imported, set the values as numeric and attached the dataset through the console and ran:

`` ts_gdp= (data=`GDP per capita, start=1871,end=2014,frequency=1, names=gdp) ``

I get to see all the values for the first variable and then follow up with the stl() but I get this error. Any clues why this shows up, although I have set the frequency=1, which is the number of observations for the unit of time, in this case a year? Thank you in advance!

```
Error in stl(GDP, s.window = "periodic") : 
  series is not periodic or has less than two periods
```

Comment: I think you can edit your line because you don't close the data string : I think you need another quote here : `ts_gdp = (data='GDP per capita', start = ....`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I did try closing the data string, but still no luck.